# Android layouts tree, human readable explanation?

Tags: android, layout, size, screen

If I write a message today is for getting details about the folder tree layouts in android.

I want to warn you now, I have read all the pages of the official documentation regarding support for different screen sizes, it is very complete, but in my opinion not really human-readable. So please, don't just copy a link to the documentation.

My question is simple:

What is the best combination of layouts folders to ensure maximum support for different screen sizes ?

Before Honeycomb, we had layout, layout-large, layout-xlarge, etc ... That's OK, but now we have sw600dp, sw360dp, sw ... Arggh stooop !

In my case, I have to make an application for android and I need to ensure maximum support.

I have some devices on hand:

Galaxy Note 10.1
Galaxy Nexus
Nexus S
Nexus 7
And ... Samsung Galaxy Spica (GT-5700)

And here are my layouts folder now:

```
layout
layout-sw360dp (for Galaxy Nexus)
layout-sw600dp (for Nexus 7)
layout-sw720dp (for Galaxy Note 10.1)
layout-480x320 (for GT-5700)
```

(and layout-*-lands)

I'm really not sure of doing things right, I thought the Nexus S would pick the layout folder, but it takes the layout-480x320, why?

So I have some questions:

```
1. Am I in the right direction?

2. Is it always necessary to create folders layout-large, layout-xlarge ... ? If so what should I put inside?

3. I do think the folder layout-480x320 is not a good solution, but I try to do things well and not make this folder is not enough.
```

Could someone tell me clearly how to do things right?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What is the best combination of layouts folders to ensure maximum support for different screen sizes ?

That is impossible to answer in the abstract.

> Am I in the right direction?

`-layout-WxH` has been deprecated for a couple of years.

> Is it always necessary to create folders layout-large, layout-xlarge ... ?

No. If you are not concerned about Android 2.x `-large` or `-xlarge` devices (e.g., Kindle Fire, NOOK) or Android 3.1 devices (0.4% of the market as of November 2012), then skipping `-large` and `-xlarge` is perfectly fine.

However, `-small` may still be relevant for you, for devices with very small screen sizes (under 3" diagonal), if you are supporting such devices.

> I do think the folder layout-480x320 is not a good solution

Correct.

> I try to do things well and not make this folder is not enough.

Then design a more flexible UI for `-layout`.

Comment: Hello,Thanks for your answer. I though that it was deprecated but I wasn't sure (-layout-WxH).Thank you for your answer for folders -xlarge and -large I didn't know anymore that it concerned just these devices. It's less confused for me now. I'll try it and a last precision.. Can I continue to use specific folder like layout-SW720dp ? And these three folders sw*dp which I spoke in the top, are they good enough? I understand that you can't give a fixed use, but in my case, what would you have do? Thanks again for your quick answer.